# Processing XML values returned from solr

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, solr

I'm querying apache solr and getting XML response in the following format

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
     <int name="status">0</int>
     <int name="QTime">10</int>
   </lst>
   <result name="response" numFound="1015" start="0">
     <doc>
        <str name="city">zzzzzzz</str>
        <str name="id">130</str>
        <long name="inst_type">2</long>
        <str name="area">yyyyyyyyy</str>
        <str name="address">
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </str>
        <str name="name">Check</str>
       <long name="_version_">1435275837198827521</long>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="city">zzzzzzz</str>
        <str name="id">130</str>
        <long name="inst_type">2</long>
        <str name="area">yyyyyyyyy</str>
        <str name="address">
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </str>
        <str name="name">Check</str>
       <long name="_version_">1435275837198827521</long>
     </doc>
     goes on..
   </result>
</response>
```

How to process the following xml file in php? I need to get the id values of the response

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Actually I want to get value of id's. "<str name="id"> values".

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: I saw that already. Instead, can you provide me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("NewFile.xml");
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
    //echo $second_gen->getName()."=><br />";
    foreach ($second_gen->children() as $third_gen) {
    //echo $third_gen->getName()."=><br />";   
        foreach ($third_gen->children() as $fourth_gen) {        
        if($fourth_gen['name']=='id') {echo "ids=>";echo $fourth_gen;}
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```